# Add write permissions to a Time Machine drive?

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, permission

Unlike other files and drives, it does not seem possible to change read/write permissions on a Time Machine drive in the Finder's *Get Info* dialog box (at least not in Monterey). The padlock icon is missing from the bottom right corner:

[image]

How can I can I change the permissions on a Time Machine drive so that I can write to it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't & I'm pretty sure if you did you'd break it. Add another volume instead. [I don't have Monterey to test this theory]

Comment: When I buy an external drive, if it's large enough, I create a TM partition, and a separate partition for other storage.  _Before_ providing it to TM for backups.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am having this issue with an external TimeMachine HFS+ volume from an old Mac (Catalina), now attached to a new Mac (Ventura). Previously, the root volume dir `/Volumes/TM` was owned and read/writable by me. Now, I cannot read `/Volumes/TM`, but I can read-only on `/Volumes/TM/Backups.backupdb`. However, on the old Mac, I had made a second dir `/Volumes/TM/RemoteBackups` for other Macs on the network to use, and I am still able to read/write and have ownership. This whole situation is very confusing, previously I had ownership on the entire volume, now only `RemoteBackups` subdir

Comment: Ventura will not use a volume formatted as HFS+ for Time Machine. It will only use APFS. [As far as I'm aware that should also apply to network volumes, but I don't use those, so I'm no authority on the topic.] You need to ask this as a new question. Almost no-one will ever see it buried down here on an old post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, and most importantly I don't recommend doing it, but it's entirely possible to create directories in an APFS Time Machine volume on Monterey and write to them. Just do it from the terminal:

Create a Folder

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/Name_of_the_TM_Save/My_Folder
```

Then unhide this folder

```
sudo chflags -R nohidden /Volumes/Name_of_the_TM_Save/My_Folder
```

Then you appropriate it:

```
sudo chown -R your_name:staff /Volumes/Name_of_the_TM_Save/My_Folder
```

And that's all.

But what can be the interest ?????
And the risk of "breaking" Time Machine.

**The best solution is as @Tetsujin indicates** to create if necessary a new volume in the APFS container supporting the TM backup.

Comment: The OP does not mention APFS.

Answer (score 0):

One usage scenario that led me to your post is a shucked WD drive on which I cannot seem to disable "intelligent" head parking, and that goes nuts in my external enclosure spinning down and spinning up. I do not need the storage space from a second partition, so just want to use an app, *Amphetamine*, to write to the drive periodically to keep it from spinning down then right back up. The question of whether this will "break" TM is an interesting one. My backup is brand new, so if something goes wrong, I'll report back.

Comment: when I had a similar issue, instead of a third party app, I used the builtin `crontab` to set a command to write to disk every minute, looked something like this; `* * * * *  date > /Volumes/TimeMachine/date.txt`. It kinda helped. However if you cannot write directly to the root location, you might still be able to write to a different subdir inside it like `/Volumes/TimeMachine/something/date.txt`